# Making Inferences from a sample

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference, sample

I am trying to teach myself basic inferential statistics by going through online video lectures. However there are some gaps in my core concepts. I have a couple of quick questions

Assume I take a sample of the heights of 100 students in 8th grade. The students were chosen completely at random and can be considered to be independent from each other

(1). If the height of these students in this sample is normally distributed, can I assume that heights of the students in my entire population will also be normally distributed

(2). Conversely if the heights of the students in the sample is not normally distributed can I assume that the heights of the students in the population is also not normally distributed

Comment: What would it mean exactly to say the height of students in a sample was normally distributed (or not normally distributed)?

Comment: I guess this is the part that I do not understand completely. Can I make any assumptions about the distribution of the population by looking at the data in the sample?